# Posting array value's to json API with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, webclient, httpresponse

i'm trying to send a post request to an online API to recieve net data, it was succesfull with normal key-value's but not with array's as value and i could't find it on the internet without creating a big amount of extra classes.

This is how i tried to post to the url with normal data (the 3th one needs an array in stead of a single object).

```
 IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("keyA","ValueA"),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("keyB", ""),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KeyC", "ValueCDE"), //array
        };
        HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
        Console.WriteLine(q.ToString());
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, q))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
                    Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to send raw data to the url but i recieved no response from it.

```
    async static void PostRawRequest(string url)
    {
        string rawr = @"{
       ""a"":""a"",
       ""b"":"""",
       ""c"": [""C"", ""D"",""F""],
       ""StickerColor"": ""red""
       }";

        string result = "";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", rawr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

}

Can anyone help me in either the first(sending array values) or second (sending raw data)?

Comment: Instead of trying to create a string by hand, just use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: You should probably drop WebClient too. It's been replaced by HttpClient which, btw can also serialize objects to Json

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use a library to handle the serialization for you. Then you can do something like this (using Newtonsoft.Json):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
    client.PostAsync(yourUri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```